# How to fix 'Broad host permissions' when publishing an extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions, publishing

I'm just publishing a Google Chrome extension and I run into the error message: "Because of the following issue, your extension may require an in-depth review:
- Broad host permissions"
And whilst I know why this is (see snippet of manifest code) I wonder what the best way to fix it is?

I know this is to do with the wildcards I'm using and I have now published the extension with specific websites to test it works as intended (it does). But for the extension to be truly effective I want it to work more universally.

```
"content_scripts"   : [{
        "matches"           : [ "http://*/*","https://*/*" ],
        "exclude_globs"     : [ "*.jpg","*.jpeg","*.gif","*.png","*.bmp","*.webp",
                                "*.css","*.swf","*.js","*.zip","*.rar","*.tar","*.tar.gz","*.tgz","*.tar.bz2","*.tbz2",
                                "*.doc","*.docx","*.ppt","*.pptx","*.xls","*.xlsx","*.pdf","*.xml","*.txt",
                                "*.mpg","*.mpeg","*.qt","*.mp4","*.m4v","*.m4a","*.mp3","*.ogv","*.ogm","*.ogg","*.oga","*.webm","*.wav",
                                "*.","*." ],
        "css"               : [ "css/inject.css" ],
        "js"                : [ "js/jquery.js" , "js/inject.js" ],
        "run_at"            : "document_start"
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources" : [
        "html/iframe/*",
        "src/options/options.html"
    ],
    "permissions"       : [
        "tabs"
        "activeTab",
        "webRequest",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
            "storage"
    ]
}
```

Comment: There's no "fix". This is Google's policy. You can use a workaround which works for now: remove `content_scripts` section and switch to programmatic injection (for example using [declarativeContent](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) API) and move `"http://*/*"` + `"https://*/*"` to [optional permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions).

Comment: I was just looking at that, but I'm unsure where the `permissions.request():` would go?

Comment: In the background script. Probably in chrome.runtime.onInstalled listener. See [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:permissions).

Comment: I have this which feels about right? ```chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {chrome.permissions.request({
permissions: ['tabs'],
          origins: [ "http://*/*","https://*/*" ]
        });
   });```

Comment: But I get this error in return for that: (Unchecked runtime.lastError: This function must be called during a user gesture
Context
html/background.html
Stack Trace
html/background.html:0 (anonymous function))

Comment: Yep. Either do it in your browser_action popup if you have one (in a 'click' listener), or in options (in a 'click' listener), or in the background script's chrome.browserAction.onClicked ([more examples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:browseraction)).

Comment: I have both a popup and an iframe, the iframe has two parts, one is the tab that is always visible and the second part of the iframe pops up when clicked. I require the use first to click on the popup for information before engaging with the iframe - it might make sense to have it when the pop up is opened?